# Drupal 7 different size sidebar per page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes

In drupal 7, I have 1 page with a sidebar of 200px width, and I need another page with the same sidebar, but it has to be 300px width.
How do I do this without creating a whole new theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will create the two different nodes and write their different templates file as per your need.You can either write the page template or node template.

EDIT:
page--node--x.tpl.php too edit node x

Comment: I also found this, I created a file page-node-1.tpl.php, and cleared the theme cache but node 1 is still the same

Comment: Are you checked that the node id for which you wrote t he template is 1.Please checked it again.This will worked for me a few months ago. page-node-node-id.tpl.php  Here node id is the id of the node for which template is created

Comment: it is node 1, it's a page, and go to admin/appearance is enough too clear the theme cache?

Comment: Is Your template file is placed in the themes folder.You can write some testing something like lorem ipsum etc. content in it so that you will find that this template is loaded for the node or not.and then checked which template is loaded for this node.

Comment: it's placed in bartik/templates, when I write something in page.tpl it shows, but when I write it in page-node-1.tpl, it doenst, so I guess it's not loaded, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: it got it, it should be : page--node--1.tpl.php, don't know why '--' is needed but it works